# How do I get a URL parameter, add it as a parameter to a webhook, then have the webhook return a link that will redirect the user?

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments, webhooks, fetch-api, query-string

For Stripe, I need to have a way to create a new onboarding link when the old one expires. In plain text, I want to:

1. Pass the Stripe ID from the URL into a webhook URL
2. Trigger the webhook
3. Wait for new link

The webhook triggers a Zapier automation that will create a new link.

3. Redirect user to new link

This is what I have so far:

```
const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
const StripeConnectedAccount = urlParams.get('StripeConnectedAccount');

fetch('https://hooks.zapier.com/hooks/catch/10517912/bthl3st'+?+StripeConnectedAccount);
```

That doesn't seem to be triggering the webhook though. Any help would be hugely appreciated.